# packer build ec2 type amazon-instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, automation, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp-packer, packer-builder

I'm building an ec2 using Packer. in the builders type there are amazon-ebs and amazon-instance (there are more but that relevant for me).
My question is, in the amazon-instance required configuration reference there are two mandatory objects:
x509_cert_path and x509_key_path

I'm having a lot of trouble with those two, first I don't understand why it is mandatory? what is the purpose of those certificates? second I don't understand what I should do, I've seen this AWS documentation [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html) and I did all those steps. What's next?

Help would be super appreciated,
thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I decided to use amazon-ebs which are not required an x509 certificate. you can close the discussion